# capture the Status change of JIRA issues through api

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I'd want to capture the status change of the JIRA issues through Python APIs. See snapshot below.
I'd used

> JIRA.transitions(issue_id, expand="transitions.fields")

method, but this is not retrieving the these information.

Any specic APIs that would return these information?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This type of information is available in the issue history (changelog). I'm afraid that Python JIRA API package cannot retrieve this type of information.

You might need to get this through regular Jira REST API using `getIssue` method extended by `expand` parameter to get history details.

**Documentation:**
https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/latest/#api/2/issue-getIssue

**Example:**
https://jira.yourdomain.com/rest/api/2/issue/KEY-1234?expand=changelog

Then you need to parse the output JSON accordingly.

**Output example:**

```json
{
  ...,
  "changelog": {
    "startAt": 0,
    "maxResults": 10,
    "total": 10,
    "histories": [
      ...,
      ...,
      {
        "id": "4023557",
        "author": { ... },
        "created": "2021-04-27T21:09:47.000+0200",
        "items": [
          {
            "field": "status",
            "fieldtype": "jira",
            "from": "1",
            "fromString": "Open",
            "to": "10003",
            "toString": "Ready"
          }
        ]
      },
      ...
```